# Spring security oauth2 always returning 403

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a Spring boot app serving Rest endpoints which I'm securing using Spring security and Oauth2.
I want to secure all my endpoints except the endpoints used to authenticate, to create an account or some info stuff.

The security configuration is like this :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private MongoTokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        //clients.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService);
        clients.inMemory().withClient("app").secret("password")
                        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(30000).authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                        .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(300000000)
                        .scopes("read");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                    .pathMapping("/oauth/confirm_access", "/access_confirmation");

    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return this.tokenStore;
    }

}


@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;
  @Autowired
  private SecurityContextService securityContextService;
  @Autowired
  private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

  @Bean
  public MongoUserDetailsManager mongoUserDetailsManager() throws Exception {
    return new MongoUserDetailsManager(userRepository, securityContextService, authenticationManagerBean(), mongoTemplate);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean())
        .userDetailsService(mongoUserDetailsManager());
  }

  @Override
  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
        authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/token", "/server/version", "/clients/register").permitAll()
        .and().csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .disable();
  }

}
```

I can access to token endpoint to get my access_token, but I want to access to other secured endpoints using this access_token (by adding the Authorization:Bearer {access_toke} to the header), I always get HTTP 403.

Did I miss something? I'm not supposed as authorized if I add the Authorization header?

My Controllers are only annotated with these @RestController, @CrossOrigin
and @RequestMapping("/url")

Comment: Can you confirm your header?  It's written as `Authorization:Bearer {token}` but generally needs to be implemented as `Authorization: Bearer {token}` (the space is super important)

Comment: I'm using Postman to test so I'm not sure the space is the issue

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 types of security configurations in case of OAuth security(as far as urls security is concerned) in Spring.

**1. Basic Security Configuration**

This class should implement `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. It will handle all those requests coming without "Bearer" token type(urls that shouldn't be oauth protected).

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;
  @Autowired
  private SecurityContextService securityContextService;
  @Autowired
  private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

  @Bean
  public MongoUserDetailsManager mongoUserDetailsManager() throws Exception {
    return new MongoUserDetailsManager(userRepository, securityContextService, authenticationManagerBean(), mongoTemplate);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean())
        .userDetailsService(mongoUserDetailsManager());
  }

  @Override
  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
        authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/token", "/server/version", "/clients/register").permitAll()
        .and().csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .disable();
  }

}
```

**2. Resource Server Configuration(OAuth Specific)**

This class is responsible for handling all those requests coming with authorization header of type `Bearer`. It should be extended from `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` class. Here you should mention all those urls with security configurations that you like to be oauth protected.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuthResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {    
        http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/resources-to-be-protected/**").and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources-to-be-protected/**").access("#oauth2.isClient()");

}
}
```